# Search Controls with substring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form where dependent details are entered by employee .Father ,mother and 
information of child he/she have.While editing information info saved in database
is binded again in form as follow.Structure of table have columns-i_empid, c_name, c_dob, i_age,c_relation. Iwant to reduce code lines .Please help me .As 
txtName,txtName1,txtName3,txtName4 have txtName substring same .Can this be helpful while binding ids with same loop

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", AutoId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", 2);
            dtTemp = dlObj.getDataTable("UID_EmpRelation",cmd);
            if (dtTemp != null && dtTemp.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                #region [if 5]
                if (dtTemp.Rows.Count == 5)
                {
                    txtName.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation1.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation2.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName3.Text = dtTemp.Rows[3]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob3.Text = dtTemp.Rows[3]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge3.Text = dtTemp.Rows[3]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation3.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[3]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName4.Text = dtTemp.Rows[4]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob4.Text = dtTemp.Rows[4]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge4.Text = dtTemp.Rows[4]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation4.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[4]["c_relation"].ToString();
                }
                #endregion

                #region [if 4]
                if (dtTemp.Rows.Count == 4)
                {
                    txtName.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation1.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation2.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName3.Text = dtTemp.Rows[3]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob3.Text = dtTemp.Rows[3]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge3.Text = dtTemp.Rows[3]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation3.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[3]["c_relation"].ToString();
                }
                #endregion

                #region [if 3]
                if (dtTemp.Rows.Count == 3)
                {
                    txtName.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation1.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge2.Text = dtTemp.Rows[2]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation2.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[2]["c_relation"].ToString();
                }
                #endregion

                #region [if 2]
                if (dtTemp.Rows.Count == 2)
                {
                    txtName.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_relation"].ToString();

                    txtName1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge1.Text = dtTemp.Rows[1]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation1.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[1]["c_relation"].ToString();
                }
                #endregion

                #region [if 1]
                if (dtTemp.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    txtName.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_name"].ToString();
                    txtDob.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_dob"].ToString();
                    txtAge.Text = dtTemp.Rows[0]["i_age"].ToString();
                    ddlRelation.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[0]["c_relation"].ToString();
                }
                #endregion

            }
```

Comment: `Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(box => box.Name.StartsWith("textBox"));` Try something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a sample and small code to demonstrate how it will work on small scale. I have took 5 text boxes having name txtName1, txtName2,..., txtName5 like wise. Now in order to get the entered text I made a loop through by numbers starting from 1 to 5.

This is the web form:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Name 1: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName1" runat="server" /><br />       
    Name 2: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName2" runat="server" /><br />
    Name 3: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName3" runat="server" /><br />
    Name 4: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName4" runat="server" /><br />
    Name 5: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName5" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" Text="Show Names" runat="server" OnClick="btnShow_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Literal ID="litNames" runat="server" />
</form>
```

This is on button click C# code:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var name = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtName" + i);
        litNames.Text += name.Text;
    }
}
```

In similar fashion you can reduce your code as follows:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", AutoId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", 2);

dtTemp = dlObj.getDataTable("UID_EmpRelation",cmd);

if (dtTemp != null && dtTemp.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for(var i = 0; i <= dtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
    {       
        var name = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtName" + (i == 0 ? "" : i));
        var dob = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtDob" + (i == 0 ? "" : i));
        var age = (TextBox)this.FindControl("txtAge" + (i == 0 ? "" : i));
        var relation = (DropDownList)this.FindControl("ddlRelation" + (i == 0 ? "" : i));

        name.Text = dtTemp.Rows[i]["c_name"].ToString();
        dob.Text = dtTemp.Rows[i]["c_dob"].ToString();
        age.Text = dtTemp.Rows[i]["i_age"].ToString();      
        relation.SelectedValue = dtTemp.Rows[i]["c_relation"].ToString();       
    }   
}
```

Use Form.FindControl if this.FindControl have some trouble. I am assuming your ddlRelation is "asp:DropDownList".

Comment: Thanks for your time. I should have think of that myself.